# If Sturm-Liouville Problem is given in uncommon way, what interval we should think for $\lambda$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

It was my exam question, and because of the question I had to dispute to my teacher about the method of solving this S.L. problem.

The equation:

$$y''+3y'+(1+\lambda^2 )y=0$$

with B.C.
$$y(0)=y'(1)=0$$

$$-----------------------$$

My point is if the equation were given as $$y''+\lambda y=0$$ we know how to solve it first assume $\lambda>0$ then $<0$ then $=0$ etc.

However we do this because characteristic equation $r^2+\lambda=0$'s character changes according to neighborhood of $\lambda=0$(some kind of critical point.)

Therefore, if the equation were $y''+3y'+(1+\lambda^2 )y=0$, and just $\lambda>0$ is given,

then our charecteristic equation becomes $r^2+3r+1+\lambda^2=0$ then discriminant is $\triangle=5-4\lambda^2 $ so the solution of charecteristic equation changes according to $\lambda=\sqrt{5/4}$.

***Should not we solve the Sturm-Liouville equation where $\lambda>\sqrt{5/4},<\sqrt{5/4}$ and $=\sqrt{5/4}$ eventhough $\lambda$ is given positive?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't have to break things into cases if you normalize the functions at one or the other endpoint. So start by solving
$$
     y''+3y'+(1+\lambda^2)y = 0,\\
      y(0)=0,\;y'(0)=1.
$$
The general solution is determined by the equation
$$
          m^2 + 3m+1+\lambda^2 = 0 \\
          (m+3/2)^2+(\lambda^2-5/4)=0 \\
          m = -3/2\pm i\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4}.
$$

This gives solutions $y(x)=Ce^{3x/2}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4} x)$ where $C$ is chosen so that
$$
    1=y'(0)=C\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4} \\
    \implies C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4}}.
$$
So
$$
    y(x,\lambda)=\frac{e^{3x/2}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4}}.
$$
This works for all $\lambda$, even in the limit as $\lambda\rightarrow\pm\sqrt{5}/2$, where L'Hopital gives
$$
     y(x,\pm\sqrt{5}/2)=xe^{3x/2}.
$$
If $\lambda^2-5/4 < 0$, then $\sin$ switches to $\sinh$ because
$$
      \sin(ix) = \frac{e^{i(ix)}-e^{-i(ix)}}{2i}= i\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}=i\sinh(x).
$$
Therefore for $\lambda^2-5/4 < 0$,
$$
      y(x,\lambda) = \frac{e^{3x/2}\sinh(\sqrt{5/4-\lambda^2}x)}{\sqrt{5/4-\lambda^2}}.
$$
The special case at $\lambda^2=5/4$ gives the same limit as before.

The eigenvalue equation becomes a power series equation in $\lambda$:
$$
      y'(1)=0=\frac{3}{2}\frac{e^{3x/2}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4}}+e^{3x/2}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda^2-5/4}x)
$$
This can be written as a power series equation in $\lambda^2-5/4$.